# QueryException (42S02)

Tags: database, laravel

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02)
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'influencingquotes.posts' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `quote_title` = gtav hyhui)

I am not sure why this Database\QueryException is occurring :(

Comment: You'll need to include your source code as well as explain what you've attempted to debug the problem thus far.

Answer (score 0):

The Error says that the `posts` table is missing, maybe you forget to run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If in database you couldn't find posts table
Then you need to try to find migration file for it 
which for laravel 5 located in project_root_dir\database\migrations
Then via command line

> php artisan migrate

2.If in database exist table, but name is wrong , for example name is post
In post model you need to specify table name

`protected $table = 'post';`

If it doesn't help, you need to write us
1.what you see in database, which tables or views exists there
2.What files you see in project_root_dir\database\migrations directory.